# Displaying a Specific View in a UINavigationController Stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In building my application which is a tab based application, from the first tab, the user has the option to view their profile information (which is specific to the app).  SO have set up `UINavigationController` with following view controllers:

```
1 - Edit profile
0 - View profile (also the root view controller for the `UINavigationController`).
```

The flow I would like to achieve is if a profile has not been set up (i.e. the first time the application is run), I would like to go directly the Edit Profile View, which right now is the default behaviour since that view is at the top of the stack.

The problem I have run into is, if the profile has been set up, how would I go directly to View Profile.  I have looked at the documentation for the `UINavgationController`, and it unclear about popping a view controller off the stack.  The method `popToViewController:animated` return an `NSArray` of items popped from the stack.  Does that mean those view controllers are no longer available, and/or is there a better method to go directly to the view controller that I want?

Comment: There are some confusing points in your questions. You say "tab based" (UITabBarController), but you are talking about navigation (UINavigationController). If you use UINav..., you push EditProfileController into the stack, and once you are done, you pop it and update ViewProfileController.

Comment: @Canopus The whole application is tab based, but the section manipulating the user account navigates through a series of screens, much like Twitter or Fourquare.

Comment: Assuming that Profile is one of your tabs, and by default it shows the ViewProfileController, and you know that the next view in the hierrarchy is EditProfileController, on -viewDidLoad, if it is the first time, push EditProfileController into the stack. And yes, "...view controllers are no longer available". Personally, --not that there is no other way -- I don't see any problem with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have two views in the navigation controller, and View is the root view controller, you can make sure that View is the one that is shown by running `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` immediately before or after that tab has been selected on the tab bar controller.

If you are in a case where you want Edit to show, run `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` followed by `pushViewController:animated:` with the Edit view controller.

When you want to pop, you can use `popViewControllerAnimated:` rather than `popToViewController:animated`. (You only have two view controllers in this nav controller, so ther is only one that will ever be popped.)

This seems pretty simple, unless I have misunderstood your question.

The array of view controllers that are returned from the `popToViewController:animated` aren't needed by most programs. I haven't really found a need to use this method myself, and, as I said, it doesn't look like you need it here.

Comment: Thanks, you understood perfectly.  I was mostly concerned with the views being removed from navigation controller entirely.